# ¿Cómo aumentar las respuestas de una búsqueda en API TwitteR?

Tags: r, twitter

Estoy intentando obtener los tweets correspondientes a un usuario de twitter a partir de la API de TwitteR con el comando userTimeLine, el problema es que me proporciona un número limitado de tweets a pesar de que le pongo n=5000, para obtener 500 tweets me proporciona aproximadamente 255.

El warning que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
mach_tweets = searchTwitter("socialmuving", n=500)
```

> ```
> Warning message:
> In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit,  :
> 5000 tweets were requested but the API can only return 218
> ```

En este caso estoy realizando una busqueda, al usar userTimeline obtengo el mismo warning. Tomando otro usuario obtengo los 500 que pido pero en caso de poner este (es el que necesito) no obtengo mas de 260.

Para el caso de una busqueda de un hastag:

```
mach_tweets2 = searchTwitter("#marypaz", n=5000)
```

> ```
> Warning message:
> In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit,  :
> 5000 tweets were requested but the API can only return 7
> ```

Solo me proporciona una lista de 7 tweets.

Comment: Hola Juan, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. ¿Has mirado la documentación para saber si hay un limite independientemente del valor que tu pongas? ¿O igual los resultados son los que hay? Mira en twitter esa busqueda que haces, por ejemplo el *hashtag* para ver cuantos resultados existen. Mira [ask] pra mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: Prueba lo siguiente: `cran_tweets <- userTimeline('cranatic', n=500);length(cran_tweets)` esto te debería retornar el valor `500`. La API `userTimeline` permite recuperar hasta 3200 twits no más. Coincido con lois6b, deberías verificar el timeline o la búsqueda para ver si efectivamente tienes la cantidad que esperas obtener. Y comparte el código de lo que estás haciendo para que podamos reproducir tu problema. Saludos

Comment: Aplicando tu código obtengo los 500 tweets pero con el usuario que pongo no me da los 500. Una vez hecho tanto la búsqueda como el userTimeline, obtengo el número de tweets que me sale en el warning.

Answer (score 0):

Bien, leído un poco de la documentación puedo decirte lo siguiente: No es un problema tuyo, ni de la forma o configuración que usas para hacer la búsqueda ni tampoco un problema del paquete `twitteR`, el problema radica en la propia Search API de Twitter (que es la que usa `twitteR`), en realidad tampoco es un problema sino una decisión de negocios, simplemente la búsqueda usando esta API no retorna todos los Tweets, según la [documentación](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El mensaje que recibes es un "warning" que básicamente te está informando que solicitaste 500 elementos y solo se logró recuperar 218. También para confirmar esto, hay un ["issue"](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR/issues/82) cerrado en el github del proyecto explicando exactamente esta situación.

#### ¿Hay solución a esto?

Si, pero con una solución técnicamente distinta y contratando alguna de las opciones de pago que puedes ver [aquí](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview).